# FLASH Bulder Type 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 2. - JSON

Tags: flash, apache-flex, json, youtube

I'm making a Youtube Downloader in Flash Builder using the tutorial on http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-tutorials/audionvideo/creating-a-downloader-for-youtube-with-flexair-2/ but I'm getting an error in my code  here

```
public function getFLVURL( sHTML:String ) : String {
                var swfArgsFound:Array = sHTML.match( /var swfArgs =(.*?);/ );
                **var swfArgsJS:JSONDecoder = new JSONDecoder( swfArgsFound[1] );**
                var swfArgs:Object = swfArgsJS.getValue();

                var url:String = 'http://youtube.com/get_video.php';
                var first:Boolean = true;
                for( var k:String in swfArgs ) {
                    if ( swfArgs[k] != null && swfArgs[k].toString().length > 0 ) {
                        url += first ? '?' : '&';
                        first = false;
                        url += k+'='+escape(swfArgs[k]);    
                    }
                }
                return url;
            }
```

The error is saying there is an incorrect number of arguments, expected 2. However I can't figure out what the second argument is. The tutorial, from what I can tell was written for Air 1.0 so maybe things have changed since the tutorial was written. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your 'starred' line is causing the error?  Are you using the [AS3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/) library?

Did you look at [the code](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONDecoder.as) for this class?

The first parameter is the string you want to decode.  The second one is named 'strict' which I assume relates to how the code is decoded.  Per the docs:

> strict Flag indicating if the JSON
>   string needs to strictly match the
>   JSON standard or not.

With all due respects, how did this get to the point where you even had to ask the question?

Comment: @Casey Wylde I know I'm being a bit of a bitch here.  But, next time before you ask for help, you should be forth some effort of your own to solve the problem.  I'm sure it took you longer to write up your question than it took me to find the answer.  And I'm sure you could have found the answer even quicker than that.

Comment: actually I did search for several hours, but I really didn't know what I was looking for so I was searching blindly for things like JSO|

Comment: @Casey Wylde next time try Googling the class name.  Or, if you're in Flash Builder you can control click on the class to bring up the code.